# Django Tastypie - Localization, db schema

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I'm relatively new to Django and Django tastypie, so my question might be quite trivial.

I'm trying to implement a RESTFUL service with tastypie for localizable text.

My Django resources are:

```
#The different languages
class Language(models.Model):
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# The different Chapters in the book
class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# The different Lines of the chapters (by sections)
class Line(models.Model):
    chapter= models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    section = models.IntegerField()
    line = models.IntegerField()

# The different translations of the line
class LineLanguage(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    text = models.TextField()
```

I then have the tastypie resources:

```
class LanguageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta: queryset = Language.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'language'
    authorization = Authorization

class ChapterResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta: queryset = Chapter.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'chapter'
    authorization = Authorization()

class LineResource(ModelResource):
    chapter = fields.ForeignKey(ChapterResource, 'chapter')
    class Meta: queryset = Line.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'line'
    authorization = Authorization()

class LineLanguageResource(ModelResource):
    language= fields.ForeignKey(LanguageResource, 'language')
    line = fields.ForeignKey(LineResource, 'line')
    class Meta: queryset = LineLanguage.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'lineLanguage'
    authorization = Authorization()
```

Initially I wanted to use only restful services (hence my url.py only contains the " `url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),`", but I'm not able to get what I want:

I want to be able to retrieve through a single restful call a particular line of text in the correct translation, but it's rather impossible without knowing the LineLanguageID.

Before using tastypie. I had some settings in my url.py that allowed me to find it by using an url of this kind `www.myapp.com/api/v1/language/chapter/section/line` (so that for eg  `www.myapp.com/api/v1/en/1/1/1` would return me the first line of the first section of the first chapter in English), But I wanted to switch to RESTFUL api (mostly because I want to experiment with backbone.js)

I believe my problem is either a bad design of my models / tastypie resources, or lack of knowledge on how to translate my models to proper tastypie resources.
What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably design your models slightly different. I don't know what your other needs are but you could probably change the models to something like this:

```
#The different languages
class Language(models.Model):
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# The different Lines of the chapters (by sections)
class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section = models.IntegerField()
    line = models.IntegerField()
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    text = models.TextField()
```

You would then have to define just one resource for the `Line` model and you would query the language/section/chapter/line with a request similar to:

```
www.myapp.com/api/v1/line/?language__abbreviation=en&section=1&chapter=1&line=1
```

If you don't want to change your models you can achieve what you want by calling the api with something like:

```
www.myapp.com/api/v1/lineLanguage/?language__abbreviation=en&line__line=1&line__section=1&line__chapter__name=1
```

Note that for both cases the resources' foreign key fields need th have the `full=True` argument set, as you need to query the foreign model's fields.

If you want to have the old url pattern used you can achieve that by defining the `override_urls` method in your LineLanguageResource that would contain the pattern that would handle the arguments from the url, pass it to some method that would then pass them to the tastypies' `dispatch_detail` method as request.GET elements.

Comment: I considered changing the schema (it's a possibility) but I was a bit concerned on the performances of such database design. I guess i will try to preserve my current database schema, and maybe evaluate if using tastypie is the best solution to my problem. Thanks!